# NIFI:how to transfer certain amount of flowfile

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to get one flowFile (from success queue) to read count attribute from  it, and then i want to get count number flowfiles and put it in flowfile List after that i will check `if flowfile list size == count` i will transfer all receveied flowfiles I  have  tried  codes   like  this:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return
int numb=(flowFile.getAttribute("count") as Double).round()
int  m=numb;
session.rollback();
def flowFiles = session.get(m)

if (flowFiles.size()==m){

 //transfer first and other files to success

    session.transfer(flowFiles, REL_SUCCESS)

}else{
   //rollback everything we got from incoming queue
    session.rollback()
}
```

but   this  logic  doesn't  work  for  me should  i  use   wait/notify  processor  or  routeonattribute processor?
can   you  give  me any  alternative  idea   of  how   can  i  make  this   task?